# NVD3 Multi Bar Chart - Add in grid lines and make sure every y axis value shows up

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, gridlines

I'm trying to create a multi bar chart, and my grid lines are not showing up and every y axis value is not showing up. Here's an image:

[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't using the default NVD3 css file